# google http requests blocked

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to perform a google search with python. But apparently google is such requests. I am using the requests module and already tried to set the headers for useragent.

This is my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
ua = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36'}                                                                

r = requests.get('http://google.com?q=how+old+is+selena+gomez', headers=ua)
content = r.content
counted = content.count('26')
print counted
```

But when I look at the returned HTML, I simply cannot find the answer.

Is there any possible solution out there?

Comment: What is the result of `print`? I tried it and it returned `6` for me. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I searched for the wrong answer. For 26 it returns 0 for me.

Comment: It returns `31` for me. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Its 42 on me . Do you wanna get old ?

Answer (score 2):

> But when I look at the returned HTML, I simply cannot find the answer.

It is b'coz you are using the wrong url.

```
http://google.com?q=how+old+is+selena+gomez
```

Will give you this page
[image]

The url you need is

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=how+old+is+selena+gomez
```

which will give you 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're (*besides what [Bitto Bennichan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677714/15164646) pointed out*), [returning bytes content by calling `.content` method](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content), you need to use [`.text` method instead which automatically decodes the content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Multiple-Answer-Box#age_answerbox.py) (if you need to save data, here's another [replit](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Answer-Box-Age-and-write-to-csv#main.py)):

```py
import requests, lxml, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  "User-agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "selena gomez age",
}

def get_age_answerbox():
  html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

  data = []

  age = soup.select_one('.XcVN5d').text
  birth_date = soup.select_one('.kZ91ed').text
  
  # list comprehension where dict() key-value pairs created
  people_also_search_for = [{
    "title": search.select_one('.rOVRL').text,
    "link": f"https://www.google.com{search.select_one('a')['href']}",
    "age": search.select_one('.C9iYEe').text
  } for search in soup.select('.PZPZlf.lLRSIb')]

  data.append({
    "age": age,
    "birth_date": birth_date,
    "people_also_search_for": people_also_search_for
  })

  print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

----------
'''
[
  {
    "age": "29 years",
    "birth_date": "July 22, 1992",
    "people_also_search_for": [
      {
        "title": "Justin Bieber",
        "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=justin+bieber+age&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3SC82KytS4gIxzcqNivNMtfgCUouK8_OCM1NSyxMrixcximYnW-kXpOYX5KQCKZCcVWJ66iJWwazS4pLMPIWkzNSk1CIFoBgAbN1xHFUAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijtZDl2N3zAhXRZc0KHdq4C4kQxA16BAgZEAQ",
        "age": "27 years"
      },
      {
        "title": "Ariana Grande",
        "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=ariana+grande+age&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3SC82KytS4gIxLdOzUypNtPgCUouK8_OCM1NSyxMrixcximYnW-kXpOYX5KQCKZCcVWJ66iJWwcSizMS8RIX0osS8lFQFoBgASMcE2FUAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijtZDl2N3zAhXRZc0KHdq4C4kQxA16BAgZEAY",
        "age": "28 years"
      },
      {
        "title": "Taylor Swift",
        "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=taylor+swift+age&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3SC82KytSAjNTckzNzLX4AlKLivPzgjNTUssTK4sXMYpmJ1vpF6TmF-SkAimQnFVieuoiVoGSxMqc_CKF4vLMtBIFoBAA8NTXJlMAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijtZDl2N3zAhXRZc0KHdq4C4kQxA16BAgZEAg",
        "age": "31 years"
      }
    ]
  }
]
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you only need to focus on the data you want to get, rather than figuring out how to make things work and tinker things if they are not doing what you intend to do.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "selena gomez age",  # query
  "gl": "us",               # country to search from
  "hl": "en"                # language
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(results['answer_box'])

--------
'''
{
  "type": "organic_result",
  "answer": "29 years",
  "thumbnail": "https://serpapi.com/searches/61729eade93ff4f184e4c0eb/images/3654b95e153f947ff7670f18ec5cf6132507384e605c2629.jpeg"
}
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.